# Generate AES key with a given length which contains a-Z0-9

Tags: java, encryption, aes

is it possible to create a secret key  using AES but with a given length and it should cointain only 0-9a-Z?

I just need a 32 characters key as a SecretKey spec :( for AES256 encryption/deceryption

Comment: I would generate a key of `floor(n*5.95419)-6` bits and then encode it as base-62 string (using _0-9a-Z_). n is the _'given length'_ (or one shorter) [5.95419 is a bout the numbers of bits you can store in one _0-9a-Z_ character (log62 / log2)]

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible to create a secret key using AES but with a given length and it should cointain only 0-9a-Z?

It is. By generating an AES secret key value, and then making sure that the ascii value of each character is within the bounds of `0-8 (48 - 57)` or `a-z (97-122)`.. Where it isn't, simply ammend the value to be within the range.

**But..**

This would make a wildly unsafe key. By limiting your values so heavily, you are effectively limiting the amount of possible combinations. Whereas normally, it is `2^256` possible combinations (considered secure at this point), you're dimishing that to much less possible combinations... which isn't secure.

Also, the above algorithm I suggested would make an awful lot of repeating values. You'd be comparing differences, and then ammending until that difference is 0.. which means:

```
For any value < the desired value.
     round value to desired value.
     Let desired value = 100;
     Let any value = 50;
     50 --> 100;
     Let any value = 60;
     60 --> 100;
```

**And ontop of that..**

A [Brute Force Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) will usually start out by testing `aaaa... x 256`. Then `(aaaa x 255) 1`. What I mean is, a brute force usually starts with alpha numeric characters. You're just making your key ripe for a cracking there.

### **AND ONTOP OF THAT..**

An AES key is defined as `128, 192 or 256` bits. That is the standard. You can't change the length. What you can do is look into the [Rijndael](http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm), which is what AES was before it became the standard. This can accept a wider range of key values.

## **AND ONTOP OF THAT**

An AES key is generated by the key schedule, the way it is for a reason. It is *designed* to be cryptographically resistant to cryptanalysis. By messing with that, you compromise the security of the entire algorithm, thus making it pretty pointless implementing the cryptographic standard, when you're going to mess with the output.

## **I CANT FIND A BIGGER FONT**

You want your output to be 32 characters long. In ASCII, that means `8 bits` per character. Or `32 x 8 = 256`. Well.. AES's recommended mode is `256 bits`, so you're in luck. You can use a hashing algorithm which will generate values that should be within the bounds of `a-z0-9`.

Comment: Can I geenrate the same key withot using aes?

Comment: I just want it to be 32 length and contains a-Z0-9

Comment: `32` characters equates to `256` bits in `ASCII`. AES has a `256` bit mode. What you can do then, is use a [hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) and truncate the output down to `256` bits. For example, [SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

Answer (score 0):

A `AES-256` key is 256 bit long, and would be too big to store in 32 characters (0-9a-Z).

However, if you relax your requirements a bit by extending your character set with 2 more characters (to 64 in total) - then you can store 6 bits of the key in one character - which then allows you to store a 192 bit AES key in the 32 characters.

Below code would create a 32 character base64 encoded string (0-9a-Z+/) of a 192 bit AES key:

```
  KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 
  keyGen.init(192); 
  SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();
  String keyBase64 = Base64.encode(key.getEncoded());
```